# Set tabSelectedTextColor for TabLayout using selector

Tags: android, android-selector

Following codes work because I added the `tabSelectedTextColor` attribute directly and selected text color will be white.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_layout"/>
```

But following codes don't work and I don't know why, maybe it is a bug!

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_layout"/>
```

**@color/tab_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Selected state defined so it's better to use it -->
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="#CCFFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

**Note:** `#CCFFFFFF` color works so it means, the view gets the `tabTextColor` attribute value correctly but doesn't recognize the `android:state_selected`  item. I tested all rational states but nothing worked.

**TabLayout.class**

Following codes copied from `TabLayout.class` and everything is clear. Don't you think getting selected text color from the selector is better way? If it is, please report it.

```
if(a.hasValue(styleable.TabLayout_tabSelectedTextColor)) {
    int selected = a.getColor(styleable.TabLayout_tabSelectedTextColor, 0);
    this.mTabTextColors = createColorStateList(this.mTabTextColors.getDefaultColor(), selected);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the selected text color then use setTabTextColors methode of TabLayout class like this:

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#ADABAE"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: That's the same as app:tabSelectedTextColor = ""..., which the question's author shows as working. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabTextColors(int, int)